# Unable to run Java EE project from root folder

Tags: eclipse, java-ee-8

I am not able to run my Java EE program by right-clicking in the folder. It's running when I right-click in the file name but it is showing "file not found" when trying to run from folder name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without a specific file, the server will default to what you've specified in the `web.xml` as a `welcome-file`, if present, otherwise return a 404 as shown.